# tcpflow for windows

Tags: networking, tcp, sniffing

Is there a tool like tcpflow for windows?
I need to sniff tcp's data only (without the headers)  .
I would prefer to use command line tool, so I can grep the output for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may always use Wireshark (or tshark.exe from the command line) to capture data and then post-process them afterwards without considering the headers.

Sample output:

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark.exe -x
Capturing on Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection (Microsoft's Packe
t Scheduler)

   0.000000 192.168.0.133 -> 192.168.0.255 SMB Mailslot Write Mail Slot

0000  ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 0e 2e 2b 35 55 08 00 45 00   .........+5U..E.  
0010  00 ce 5f 6e 00 00 80 11 57 dc c0 a8 00 85 c0 a8   .._n....W.......  
0020  00 ff 00 8a 00 8a 00 ba 95 f3 11 02 a3 0a c0 a8   ................  
0030  00 85 00 8a 00 a4 00 00 20 45 43 45 4a 46 45 45   ........ ECEJFEE  
0040  4d 45 4a 46 44 46 4b 43 41 43 41 43 41 43 41 43   MEJFDFKCACACACAC  
0050  41 43 41 43 41 43 41 41 41 00 20 45 4e 46 44 45   ACACACAAA. ENFDE  
0060  49 45 50 45 4e 45 46 43 41 43 41 43 41 43 41 43   IEPENEFCACACACAC  
0070  41 43 41 43 41 43 41 43 41 41 41 00 ff 53 4d 42   ACACACACAAA..SMB  
0080  25 00 00 00 00 18 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   %...............  
0090  00 00 00 00 00 00 ff fe 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 04   ................  
00a0  00 02 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................  
00b0  00 5c 00 04 00 5c 00 03 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 1b   .\...\..........  
00c0  00 5c 4d 41 49 4c 53 4c 4f 54 5c 54 57 42 5f 4d   .\MAILSLOT\TWB_M  
00d0  41 49 4c 53 4c 4f 54 00 29 7a 70 4b               AILSLOT.)zpK
```

**Update:**

If you need to capture packets on the local machine (loopback device), you should use the excellent `RawCap` tool to capture a pcap file, then use Wireshark on the captured file as usual.

Comment: Edited and added sample output. It is parallel hex & ascii.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/downloads/simsong/tcpflow/tcpflow-win-1.3.0.zip) is a tool for Windows that's about as much like tcpflow as possible. :-)

I.e., it *IS* tcpflow, compiled for Windows.  I haven't tried it, but I assume it works.  It's a "zipball", so you'll need some software that can extract from a Zip archive.

Comment: `pcap_fake.cpp:pcap_open_live: tcpflow was compiled without LIBPCAP. Will not live capture.` hm.